# How to have jQuery refer to a newly popped up window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

In the django function showRelatedObjectLookupPopup, I'd like to bind a function to a button in the newly popped up window, but I don't know how to refer to the new window. Here is what I have tried:

```
function showRelatedObjectLookupPopup(triggeringLink) {
// other function stuff omitted
    var name = triggeringLink.id.replace(/^lookup_/, '');
    name = id_to_windowname(name);
    var win = window.open(href, name, 500, 700, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes');

    win.onload = function () {
         $(document).ready(function() {
               $("input.default").hover(function () {alert('hovered')})})};
    win.focus();
    return false;
}
```

But this binds to the button in the original window.

Comment: You *should* (as in, untested by me) be able to use $(win.document).ready(function(){ ... });, instead of assigning an anonymous function to win.onload. $(document).ready() was created as a replacement for onload(), however I'm not sure how well it works for other windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are referring to the current window's document when you use

```
win.onload = function() { $(document).ready(...
```

try this:

```
win.onload = function() { $(win.document).ready(...
```

and likewise, give a context to your input selector:

```
 $("input.default", win.document).hover(...
```